# C++ initalize class values after constructor

Tags: c++, class

I have a class like this:

```
class test{
private:
    anotherClass _someVar;
public:

    test(){}; 

    void load() {
        anotherClass _someVar = anotherClass(.....);
    }
};
```

But this keeps getting the error no default constructor exists for class "anotherClass". But if I move the function `load()` into the constrcutor I also get the same error.

```
class test{
private:
    anotherClass _someVar;
public:

    test(){
        anotherClass _someVar = anotherClass(.....);
    }; 

};
```

Lastly, if this is illegal in c++, is there a way I can generate a class variable within a function of that class that can be shared to other functions of that same class? For that specific instance that is.

Comment: Use [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Comment: Besides the issue you seem to have (which is hard to help you with without a proper [mre]) also remember that `anotherClass _someVar = anotherClass(.....);` defines a *second* new and distinct and separate variable with the name `_someVar`.

Comment: For starters, `anotherClass _someVar` in method/constructor creates a new variable, unrelated to the class member. Removing the type would still give you the error though, as @Evg said you need to use a member init list.